# how to detect day light saving in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the current date and time of your timezone in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305350/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-of-your-timezone-in-java)

I have developed a Attendance System and in use for India. Our servers are in US and since they are using PDT. My code reflects time one hour ahead.

say its 9:00 am IST ---- I get the time as 10:00 am IST

other than detecting one hour from the time, which will be a temporary solution.

Pls suggest me some way to overcome this situation

Comment: It's not *at all* clear what you're doing here, partly because you haven't shown any code at all. Please give a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem, and read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if a given Date is affected by daylight saving, use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(timezone); // omit timezone for default tz
c.setTime(date); // your date; omit this line for current date
int offset = c.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
```

0 means no DST, any other value (most likely 3600000) means that this date is affected by DST