# How to convert an offset from GMT to the local timezone?

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have two inputs:

- a date value
- an integer (+8 or -3 or such) that represents the offset from GMT

Using Java, how can I convert the given date value into the corresponding date/time in the local timezone? There doesn't seem to be any timezone offset function in the Date class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If you don't want to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)) Use [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) with [`setRawOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setRawOffset(int)) with code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19378721/360211

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(rawOffsetinMiliSeconds) to get a timezone value.
**Working Example:**

```
Date now = new Date();  
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
sdf1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
System.out.println(sdf1.format(now));  
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone((TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(5*1000*3600))[0]));  
System.out.println(sdf2.format(now));
```

Comment: A "time zone" and a "time zone offset" are two different things.  Using this code will give you the *first* time zone that uses this offset, but that's not necessarily the correct time zone.

Comment: RTFQ He wants the "date/time in the local timezone" and not the timezone name of choice