# Android - Change UTC time to local time

Tags: android

I am getting from a service - Date object that contains an UTC time zone date.

How can i change it to the current phone time zone?

Comment: Greetings, This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19378721/5059472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date getDateTime = fmt.parse(utcDateAndTime);
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
String getLocalDateTime = fmt.format(getDateTime);
System.out.println("Local date/time: " + getLocalDateTime);
```