# How to know the TimeZone by using Date class in java

Tags: java, date

How to get the timezone from a date object of the system in java ?
Like EST,PST,MST.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.Date` does not contain timezone information. You can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1522571/4074715) for some options.

Answer (score 1):

Java Date class can't get timezone directly.
You can see more details as below link.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305350/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-of-your-timezone-in-java
```

Following is the way to get timezone using java.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
TimeZone timeZone = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

More details about timezone, [here.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html)