# Android - Calendar.getInstance has the hours value set to zero

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm trying to find the current time in my java code.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
    String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);
    ((TextView) (mainView.findViewById(R.id.l1))).setText(localTime);
```

For some reason the textview displays 01:08 AM instead of 8:08 PM.

Comment: Do you want to always get the current time in a particular time zone?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Zero or one? Your title says “hours value set to zero”, but the text says “ 01:08 AM”. Which seems to be the result of `SimpleDateFormat.format()`, not the hour value from the `Calendar`. Also, what is the result when you run the code at other times of day?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Running your code at 16:00 in my time zone I get `16:00 PM`.

Comment: Tristan Wiesepape, welcome to Stack Overflow! People asking for clarification is normal here. Even if your question has been answered already, it will be helpful for other readers to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51470476/edit) and provide the answers to what @TimBiegeleisen and I myself asked. Please. Also because we’d love to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 12 hour time (8:08 PM instead of 20:08 PM) make sure to change your HH to hh like so:

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

That doesn't explain why you're seeing 01:08 AM, but it's a start. I tried the exact same code out on my system, and the time displayed properly. So, I'm not sure where your issue is. My guess is that you either have your system clock set incorrectly, or more likely your experiencing a weird issue with the Calendar and Date libraries. If you continue to experience problems I would recommend switching to the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html) library. It's awesome, and it fixes all of the little issues you'll run into while using the Date and Calendar libraries.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the *java.time* classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

As stated in [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51470666/642706) by Don Brody, your formatting pattern was incorrect, using `HH` (for 24-hour clock) where it should have been lowercase `hh` (for 12-hour clock). You likely also have a problem with your JVM’s current default time zone not being set to what you expect.

Also… Your problem is moot. You are using terrible old classes that were **supplanted years ago by *java.time***.

```
LocalTime                                  // Represent time-of-day without date and without time zone.
.now()                                     // Capture the current time-of-day as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to pass the optional `ZoneId` argument to specify explicitly the desired/expected time zone.
.format(                                   // Generate a `String` representing our time-of-day value.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT )  // Automatically localize rather than hard-code a specific formatting pattern.
    .withLocale( Locale.US )               // Locale determines the human language and cultural norms used in localizing.
)                                          // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 10:09 PM

## Use *java.time*

You are using terrible old classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Get the current time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now() ;  // Capture the current time-of-day using the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Better to explicitly state the desired/expected time zone than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.now( z ) ;
```

Generate a string in AM-PM format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "hh:mm a" ) ;  // Lowercase `hh` for 12-hour clock, uppercase `HH` for 24-hour clock.
String output = lt.format( f ) ;
```

Even better, let *java.time* automatically localize for you.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output2 = lt.format( f2 ) ;
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ENTF8Q).

> lt.toString(): 22:09:19.825
>
> output: 10:09 PM
>
> output2: 10:09 PM

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()).getTime()
```

Check out this other question that might be an answer to your problem. 
[How to get the current date and time of your timezone in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305350/how-to-get-the-current-date-and-time-of-your-timezone-in-java)

Comment: I don’t think it makes any difference. You will get the current time just as in the question (and just as in the question the `Date` object cannot hold a time zone in it).