# Android get Current UTC time

Tags: java, android, datetime, time, utc

What is the function to get the current UTC time. I have tried with System.getCurrentTime but i get the current date and time of the device.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use ``new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())``?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` does give you the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. The reason you see local times might be because you convert a `Date` instance to a string before using it. You can use `DateFormat`s to convert `Date`s to `String`s in any timezone:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
String gmtTime = df.format(new Date());
```

Also [see this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java).

Comment: I want to user UTC+2 , how can I do tht

Comment: new Date() will return the current system date! if user changes the time/date it will return wrong values!

Comment: val c = Calendar.getInstance()
                        c.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
                        c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2)