# Android: getting Time in GMT+(desired number)

Tags: android, time

I am using this code to give me GMT time:

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

The time is in GMT but I am in GMT+12. Is there a very simple way to get the time in GMT+12?

Thanks.

Comment: You can get the current Date & Time dependant of your Android System by using `Calendar.getInstance()`. Maybe the Calendar object has what you need.

Comment: This may help: [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014903/getting-gmt-time-with-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+12:00");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    String time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    Log.e("time","is"+time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Time(String timezone)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#Time%28java.lang.String%29) constructor:

```
Time now = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
```