# ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 22 Apr 2015 05:45:42 GMT"

Tags: android, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm tryint to transform "Wed, 22 Apr 2015 05:45:42 GMT" to "yyyy MM dd - HH:mm"

But that string does not fit in all these simpledateformats, it gives exception in all three

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'");
```

Comment: Do you have any CrashLog ?

Comment: what is your locale ? try with `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US)` `

Comment: i'm in spain, and crash log is question title: ParseException: Unparseable date: “Wed, 22 Apr 2015 05:45:42 GMT”

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10186327/1576416

Comment: You are writing `EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z` which is single d. write dd in place of d

Comment: this app will be used by users in all the world, not only USA or SPAIN, and will parse dates comming from events in all the world, not only USA or SPAIN so... must i set locale ?

Comment: you should always specify a Locale. Did you try with the locale ?

Comment: i tryed with dd instead of d and same problem

Comment: wich locale blackbelt? this app is for all ther world

Comment: @AndroidUser99 The code works fine for me. No exceptions
`new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'Z'");` will not work, the other 2 are fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem since I am sitting in a non-english-speaking country, too. The solution is to specify English as language because your input contains an English word/abbreviation (look at the day of week "Wed"!). Following solution works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date d = sdf.parse("Wed, 22 Apr 2015 05:45:42 GMT");
SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd - HH:mm", Locale.ROOT);
System.out.println(out.format(d)); // output in the system timezone
```

It does not matter what your app is for (worldwide or not). **The only fact which matters is the language of your text input.** If this is varying in language then and only then you have first to determine the language of the device in question (probably `Locale.getDefault()`) and set it on your `SimpleDateFormat`-object.

Comment: thanks, solved with new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",Locale.ENGLISH)

Answer (score 0):

Use small z in date format

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'z'");
```

I have checked it with below code, it is working.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    try {
        Date date =simpleDateFormat.parse("Wed, 22 Apr 2015 05:45:42 GMT");
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"date : "+date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited there should be dd instead of d and z should be in lower case.