# Need help display indian city's current time using android

Tags: android

Dear Friends,

I am developing on android application for one Indian city,In my application contain information about some Indian city like weather,some place and current time. I need solution for wherever user launch my application ,my application will display  Indian city's current time.How is possible to applicable  this logic,Basically i display time for  device's current time in my app.so i am struggle with this part.please give solution for that.

Thanks Friends

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30");
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty difficult to understand your problem, next time try to make it clearer.
If you need to display the time which is stored in the device
just use

> getTime()

For weather you need to use Google's weather service and retrieve values form the server.

For IST Use this time server

> time-a.nist.gov
>   Or http://www.pool.ntp.org/zone/asia

just use anyone of these

Comment: i asked,In case user launch my app in USA,I want to display India's time,I don't want current device's time.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correct, you need to display current IST regardless of the device timezone.

If that is the case, then you would need to get UTC and convert it to IST. As an example, refer this SO .[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818086/android-get-current-utc-time)