# Converting unix timestamp to date in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, timezone, timestamp

I have a timestamp I want to convert to a date. I tried this timestamp: 1336425840. This should be Mon, 07 May 2012 21:24:00 GMT, where GMT is the timezone the emulator should be set to. I tried this:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(1336425840*1000);
Date d = c.getTime();
Log.i("MyTag", "Hours: " + d.getHours());
```

The result is: Hours: 23.

So it seems like the returned date is computed according to GMT+2, which is the timezone set for my system. I expected g.hetHours() to return 21, since the emulator's timezone seems to be set to GMT.

Also, that timestamp results from reading the actual date in C using mktime, which seems to return the correct timestamp. But Java seems to refer to a different timezone. Am I doing anything wrong? Why isn't Mon, 07 May 2012 21:24:00 GMT returned?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818086/android-get-current-utc-time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `1336425840*1000` will give you a value outside the regular range of `int`. In fact, if you would print the full date of the `Calendar` object, you'll see it displays `Thu Jan 08 23:56:50 GMT 1970`, which explains the `23` hours you see.

Change the multiplication to: (note the `L` at the end)

```
c.setTimeInMillis(1336425840 * 1000L);
```

// Edit: easy to confirm:

```
System.out.println((1336425840 * 1000L > Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

:)

Comment: Yes, I just found it out myself. I noticed the 1970 :-D Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `DateFormat` object, and then set the time zone with [`setTimeZone()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29).

Comment: Because by default it uses the current time zone of the computer you're on. You need to tell it to use GMT instead.