# How to get global date and time in android?

Tags: android

In my application some functionality get closed after 9:00 PM. Its working fine if date setting of device is auto updated. But suppose right now its 10:00 pm and user changed the time 10:00 Pm to 08:00 Pm then my code is working. I want to avoid that thing.

Comment: why dont you use system's date and time?

Answer (score 0):

Get the system time in UTC (Universal Coordinate Time).  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818086/android-get-current-utc-time) gives it in more detail

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("gmt"));
Calendar cal =   df.getCalendar();
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
if (hour > 21 && hour < 9)  // or 9:00pm in your time-zone converted to gmt...
{
    // Do something, or don't do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the external time service like [this one](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm). anything else like `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `new Date()` can be "hacked" by user