# how to get current original Time irrespective of the device time?

Tags: android, date, datetime

Today is October 21 2014. I set me Android phone time to Oct 20 2014.
What I want is the original current time from the device. I heard it possible.

What I have done is test these codes:

```
            SimpleDateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
            Time now = new Time("GMT+05:30");
            now.setToNow();
            now.format("%c");
            String l1 = sdf.format(new Date(now.toMillis(true)));
            String l2 = sdf.format(new Date(now.toMillis(false)));
            String l3 = sdf.format(new Date(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30")).getTimeInMillis()));
            String l4 = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            String l5 = sdf.format(new Date(new Date().getTime()));
```

All of the above Strings l1,l2,l3,l3,l4,l5 have returned same date i.e "20-10-14".
But I wanted the original current time i.e "21-10-14".

Any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android get Current UTC time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818086/android-get-current-utc-time)

Comment: What does "original current time" mean?

Comment: "original current time" means whats the actual time in the world/Your Area. Not on your device.

Comment: Then you should use something like webservice to get the time from internet.

Comment: you should refer this answer on SO 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049912/how-can-i-get-the-network-time-from-the-automatic-setting-called-use-netw'

Comment: have you found the solution yet?