# How to get all data at each month from Firebase for calculation in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

There are multiples dates and data for each date. Each date and data store under a unique key.

```
"Data":{
   "K2ngvpioRUYF4bRM07Da5cbAjE53":{
      "-M3jNjCuGdMCwt1Czpwz":{
         "Date":"2020-3-30",
         "Scale":"3"
      },
      "-M3jQWxm7z0EQYgkVenX":{
         "Date":"2020-4-29",
         "Scale":"4"
      },
      "-M5hxn-rCJICUvRcMZJu":{
         "Date":"2020-4-24",
         "Scale":"2"
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to calculate the total number of scales for monthly (The main point is monthly). Instead of using "startAt" and "endAt":

```
   Query query = ref.orderByChild("Date").startAt("2020-3-1").endAt("2020-3-31");
   Query query2 = ref.orderByChild("Date").startAt("2020-4-1").endAt("2020-4-30");
```

Is there any better way to loop for all month and year? I think the above code is hard if I have dates of different years and months.

Comment: first of all, consider add date in UTC format on database see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818086/android-get-current-utc-time for UTC date then consider to move on to firestore which have more advance query option so maybe your problem solve

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about how UTC format will help in looping for all month and year

Comment: This answer will help you out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/67669844/8168140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `ref` object is pointing to the database root, then your reference is not correct since you are missing the `Data` and the ID of the user from it. See the `Data` and the `K2ngvpioRUYF4bRM07Da5cbAjE53` are present in your tree? Both children should be added to your query. Besides that, you are using for the `Date` property, String values which is actually also not correct. You should use a Timestamp, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

That being said, a correct query should look like this:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = ref.child("Data").child(uid) //Added both children
    .orderByChild("Date")
    .startAt(startLongValue)
    .endAt(endLongValue);
```

Comment: Hi, can I know what do the startLongValue and endLongValue mean?

Comment: Those are the exact Long values, that you should pass to those methods. Here `.startAt("2020-3-1")` you are passing a String representation, you need to use a Long, as explained in my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data). Passing String values, will never work.

Comment: Hi, I have improved my question and would like to ask for your help. I will click the checkmark if your answer is helpful. Thank you for spending your time for help.

Comment: I rolled back the question as it is different than the initial one. Please don't edit questions with other questions. If you encounter new problems, it's best to post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: You need to store dates like "2022-05-08" OR "2020-12-01". add 0 before a month and date less than 10. This trick works for me.