# gson serialization of Date field in MS WCF compatible form

Tags: android, serialization, gson

I access a web service in a POST method. I need to send to the server a json serialized object. In my Android class I have some string fields and a Date field. This Date field gets serialized like this:

```
.... TouchDateTime":"Oct 6, 2010 5:55:29 PM"}"
```

but to be compatible with the web service I need to have it like:

```
"TouchDateTime":"\/Date(928138800000+0300)\/"
```

I found an interesting article about Deserialization in here: http://benjii.me/2010/04/deserializing-json-in-android-using-gson/ I think I need to do something like this. Could you give me a helping hand ?

Comment: Also, you could see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date

Comment: I used http://stackoverflow.com/a/2453820/8524 to get the TimeZone offset for the above.  How did you do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anybody needs it, here is how I did it.
1. Create a new class DateSerializer and put in it:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class DateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Object> 
{
    public JsonElement serialize(Date date, Type typeOfT, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        return new JsonPrimitive("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }

    public JsonElement serialize(Object arg0, Type arg1,
            JsonSerializationContext arg2) {

        Date date = (Date) arg0;
        return new JsonPrimitive("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }
}
```

And here is how I use it:

```
   public static JSONObject Object(Object o){
    try {
        GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
        DateSerializer ds = new DateSerializer();
        gsonb.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, ds);
        Gson gson = gsonb.create();


        return new JSONObject(gson.toJson(o));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you add "Date()" and the / character? I've seen it in numerous examples but I just can't wrap my head around it. Why not just transfer the milliseconds as a number? Thanks

Comment: @JayPea because that is part of the retarded WCF .NET DateTime format. If you see it in JSON, it's likely the API is also exceptionally retarded in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs both serialization and deserialization, I've prepared a GsonHelper for it:
[How to parse .net DateTime received as json string into java's Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127529/how-to-parse-net-datetime-received-as-json-string-into-javas-date-object/15323305#15323305)