# Serialize Java Date to .Net Json date format

Tags: java, c#, json, date, datetime

Writing Android app to interact with already existing .Net API and ran into date serialization problem. I know that .Net Json date format is /Date(timestamp-timezone)/, however even if I format it like this, I still get error: `'There was an error deserializing the object of type ShoutsOut.Entities.MobileUser. DateTime content '\/Date(1469457720840-0000)\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.'`

Full stack trace:

```
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) 
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterDataContractMessageFormatter.ReadObject(Message message) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SingleBodyParameterMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I'm formatting it like this:

```
public static String toJson(Date date) {
    return "\\/Date(" + date.getTime() + "-0000)\\/";
}
```

Tried to:

- Remove timezone
- Remove / /
- add ' between the date

Found slightly different format `"\"\\/Date("+date.getTime+"-0500)\\/\""`, didn't work either

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to share the raw JSON you are trying to deserialize without any added code escaping?

Comment: `"Expires":"\"\\/Date(1469515755860-0000)\\/\""`
I think I can see the problem now, problem is how do I write \/ part without escaping?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30929414/1897229) solved it for me, basically had to change date data type to DateTime from Joda time library, and implemented custom serializer/deserializer