# How to parse Time PT15H30M received as json string int Time object?

Tags: java, android, wcf, time, gson

I called a WCF web service in my android project. my web service returns data from sql server database. i get DateTime and Time (UTC) and get a json like below:

```
{"CreateDate":"\/Date(1503952200000+0330)\/","FromTime":"PT15H30M"}
```

I searched and read below link, with this link, i can solve DateTime problem but for Time data type, i have another problem. my problem is:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: PT15H30M time
```

helping link was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127529/how-to-parse-net-datetime-received-as-json-string-into-javas-date-object).

How to solve Time data type jsonSyntaxException?

Comment: how do you get this error? what do you do? add your code!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I called a wcf service and get a json string, when i used gson and i want to map my time, i get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PT15H30M` related to [ISO 8601 time intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals). That string means “fifteen and one-half hours”. It is *not* a time-of-day.

I think `GSON` doesn't support time interval.

It uses `new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(/* ... */).create();`

So I would add `private String FromTime;` as String and parse :

```
java.time.Duration duration = java.time.Duration.parse(FromTime); // PT15H30M
 // duration.get(java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES) // whatever you want
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can't understand what you said in second line ... duration object. can you more explain? Thanks again

Comment: @Fahim suppose you want to convert JSON string to Java object. Since (I believe) you cannot parse intervals on the fly, you can only convert it to variable as String and parse it inside your Android object. I don't know where you use intervals so cannot help here

Comment: Thanks . yeah i save in string var and then i set in Time object. Thanks

Comment: @Fahim Just keep in mind that a Duration is not the same as a Time. A duration is an [**amount of time**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676793/7605325), such as *"2 days and 3 hours"* or *"1 hour, 10 minutes and 25 seconds"*, and a Time is a time of the day, such as *10 AM* or *15:30*. Although both use the same words (hour, minutes, second, etc), they represent different concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by Shoustin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46022474/642706) is correct. Here's more related to the context of the Question.

## Count-from-epoch

The `1503952200000` is *perhaps* a count of milliseconds since the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of [`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

## Offset-from-UTC

The `+0330` looks like an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). The problem is that we cannot tell if that means the count-from-epoch is in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) and we should adjust three and a half hours, or if the count-from-epoch has already been adjusted by three-and-a-half hours. I will go with the former.

This is a *terrible* format for communicating date-time values as text. If you have any control, change to using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings.

```
long count = Long.parseLong( "1503952200000" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( count ) ;

ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( "+0330" ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( offset ) ;
```

## Duration

As Shoustin explained, the "PT15H30M" is a [span-of-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) of fifteen hours and thirty minutes — not a time-of-day.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT15H30M" ) ;
```

You can add that to your [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) if you want to arrive at another point on the timeline.

```
OffsetDateTime odtLater = odt.plus( d ) ;
```

See this code run live at [IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/YANgb8).

> count: 1503952200000
>
> instant.toString(): 2017-08-28T20:30:00Z
>
> odt.toString(): 2017-08-29T00:00+03:30
>
> odtLater.toString(): 2017-08-29T15:30+03:30

## Invalid Iran time?

By the way, I am confused by the offset of three and a half hours. Looking at the list of [current time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), the only case of a +03:30 offset is by [`Asia/Tehran`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Standard_Time) time zone. But that is for standard time, not the Daylight Saving Time (DST) in effect during the given August date. For the date of **2017-08-29, there is no offset of +03:30** being used anywhere on Earth.

So I suspect you have been given faulty data. I suspect the count-from-epoch was calculated separately, and the offset was glued on after-the-fact. This is an example of why your input string format is such a poor design. Stick to ISO 8601, and avoid tracking time as a count-from-epoch.

And use time zone whenever it is known, rather than a mere offset-from-UTC. An offset is only a number of hours and minutes. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future offsets in use at various points in time by a particular region. The `ZonedDateTime::toString` method wisely extends the ISO 8601 to append the zone name in square brackets.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( "2017-08-29T15:30+04:30[Asia/Tehran]" ) ;
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

> 2017-08-29T15:30+04:30[Asia/Tehran]

Tip: Generally best to exchange date-time data in UTC, as `Instant` objects or the ISO 8601 equivalent.