# Get GMT Time in Milliseconds using JAVA

Tags: java, uti

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get GMT Time in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236052/get-gmt-time-in-java)

I have taken the reference of the below 2 link :

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5236123/960436)
[link2](http://shivendra-tripathi.blogspot.in/2010/02/date-with-javautildate.html#comment-form)

But I want the GMT date in milliseconds.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @Mark I think you have not read the question properly. I have taken the reference of the link that you have given in that I am getting date but i want the date in milliseconds On that I stuck. Do you have any Idea????

Comment: I don't know why ppl down voted the question without giving any proper reason.

Comment: It does give it in milliseconds

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`Calendar#getTimeInMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

Comment: That is the most complicated and inefficient way of getting the GMT time I have seen. :D Under all this it has to call `System.currentTimeMillis()` which returns the time in millis for GMT.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Why do you assume OP always wants the *current* time?

Comment: That is true, but if you need to store the GMT time in millis, you can use `long` for that too.

Comment: Will it also handle daylight saving correctly?

Answer (score 27):

You can use [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) it returns "the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC."

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Will do it :)

Comment: Doesn't that use the system time rather than just using GMT? If so, wouldn't this cause problems if you need the milliseconds to be standardized across more than one time zone?

Comment: This returns the exact same result as the accepted answer, but is much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Calendar Class to create an instance with GMT as the timezone.

From that you can get the time in milliseconds.

see below code sample.

```
public class TimeTest {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        System.out.println(cal.currentTimeMillis());

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For current time in millis always prefer `System.currentTimeMillis()` and also if you are using `Calendar` prefer `cal.getTimeInMillis()` instead of `cal.getTime().getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

Use [getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) function:

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
>   represented by this Date object.