# Convert current date & time to equivalent GMT date & time

Tags: java

I used the below code where  I've printed the modified GMT date in `String` & in `Date` format, it's giving me two different values.

```
Date initial = new Date();  
DateFormat dateFormatter = DateFormat.getInstance();  
dateFormatter.setTimeZone (TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  
String gmtS = dateFormatter.format(initial);             
Date gmt = dateFormatter.parse(gmtS);              
System.out.println("Data type is Date    = " + gmt);
System.out.println("Data type is String "+gmtS);
```

### Output

gtm where value id of type `Date` = `Thu Jul 03 23:15:00 EDT 2014`
gmtS where value id of type `String` = `7/4/14 3:15 AM`

But I want to see the value (`7/4/14 3:15 AM`) as a `Date` type.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5236052/642706).

Answer (score 0):

When you output a `Date` by calling `toString()` (which is what `System.out.println("Data type is Date    = " + gmt);` does) you will get that `Date` according to the system time zone, because that is what [`Date.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) returns.

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```
>
> where:
>
> ```
>  ...
>  zzz is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time). Standard time 
>      zone abbreviations include those recognized by the method parse. If time 
>      zone information is not available, then zzz is empty - that is, it 
>      consists of no characters at all.
> ```

So, to get the output you expect use your `dateFormatter` to `format` it again.

```
String gmtS = dateFormatter.format(initial);             
Date gmt = dateFormatter.parse(gmtS);              
System.out.println("Data type is Date    = " + dateFormatter.format(gmt));
```

Comment: But that'll be again of type String. I need the final date value should be of type Date with value 7/4/14 3:15 AM

Comment: @SouravBag Then you will need to change your computer's timezone to UTC. This is how `Date` works (in Java). As an example, what is the date and time where you are right now? Here it is 11:36 PM on July 3, 2014. You'll notice that where you are right now (although you record the time differently) is still contemporaneous with my instant of time.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2019-02-07T19:15:29.123456Z

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using date-time classes that are terribly troublesome, with many flaws in design.

First, you should know that `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC by definition. But its `toString` method tells a lie, dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the text representing the moment in the `Date` object.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

### `Instant`

For a moment in UTC, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html). Like `java.time.Date` it represents a moment always in UTC (but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds versus milliseconds). Indeed, you can convert easily back-and-forth between `Date` and `Instant` by using new methods added to the old class.

Unlike `toString` on `Date`, the `toString` method on `Instant` always tells the truth. The method generates text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `T` in the middle separates the date portion from the time portion. The `Z` on the end is short for UTC and is pronounced “Zulu”.

> Instant.now().toString(): 2019-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z

### `OffsetDateTime`

The `Instant` class is a basic building-block class in *java.time*, with limited functionality. If you want more flexible formatting, use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class with the offset set to UTC.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or skip the `Instant` class.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

To generate text representing the value of the `OffsetDateTime` object, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow as this has been covered many many times already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).