# Date in UTC in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a table which has field with data type as DATETIME. I persist a record in this table using java and I calculate current date as as following.

```
Date date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).getTime();
```

But When I check my table, it again converts this time into local timezone.

Can some one please explain to me, how to store date in UTC timezone in database.

@Code

I have a db entity 'Referral' corresponding to table with date member data type as java.util.Date and using hibernate to save it.

```
Referral ref = new Referral();
ref.setCreationDate(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).getTime());
referralDAO.save(ref);
```

Thanks

Jitendra

Comment: Show us your code for retrieving and interpreting the DATETIME, that might be where things are going wrong.

Comment: Does database connection properties has got something to do with it?

Comment: In your code, all the timezone work you do is lost when you call calendarInstance.getTime(). Two questions: 1. Are you sure that the right value is not being stored? Try changing your machine's timezone. If the results are then presented in the new timezone, your data is correct, it is just a presentation issue. 2. What is your database schema -- are you using DateTime or Timestamp? See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: I am using DateTime in mysql. I am directly checking database records using mysql client.

Comment: @dilium, "In your code, all the timezone work you do is lost when you call calendarInstance.getTime().", then how could we retain time in UTC.

Comment: It seems like the problem lies in how the `Referral` class gets the information into the database. What is `Referral`? What does the documentation say for `setCreationDate`? As you have it written, you are passing a UTC time to it (as a `long`), but according to your investigation, it is getting converted to local time somewhere before it gets to MySql. Do you have control over the `Referral.setCreationDate` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySql DATETIME is stored in a time zone agnostic manner. It just stores year/month/day/hour/minute/second

How you interpret that information is up to you and your application.
If you are storing it as UTC, then when  you retrieve it you must make sure to interpret it as UTC as well.

You might be interested in this SO question: [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

As mentioned in the answer to that question:

> java.util.Date is *always* in UTC.
>   What makes you think it's in local
>   time? I suspect the problem is that
>   you're displaying it via an instance
>   of Calendar which uses the local
>   timezone, or possibly using
>   Date.toString() which also uses the
>   local timezone.

Comment: I am trying to store in UTC but It is getting stored in local timezone.

Comment: See @Dilum Ranatunga's comment - are you _sure_ it's not being stored in UTC, or is it just presentation? Try doing a SELECT from inside mysql's commandline interface, to remove all the layers of reinterpretation

Comment: @Jitendra - Have you looked into `Referral`, as I mentioned in a comment on the  main question?

Answer (score 2):

Date in Java is just a long. It is agnostic of any time zones. When you pass your Date/Timestamp to the database via JDBC driver, it interprets it as time in the session time zone which is your JVM time zone.

Some databases, like Oracle and PostgreSQL, have data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE. I don't believe MySQL has it. You can either switch your JVM time zone to UTC or use a string field and format your Date with SimpleDateFormat.