# Calculate time in JSP by GMT

Tags: jsp, cookies, struts2, gmt

I have a small problem here, I am passing a list with some events to JSP with Struts2, the list contains a row with events start time. I need to calculate this time by GMT, because of GMT value from cookies which was set by the user. The problem is the time row I am getting from database is in String format (why? too much to tell) something like 01:00, so, any ideas or advices how can I? maybe some sort of JS or jQ, or server-side solutions?

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java) can help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I found nothing about what I need :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to parse the string that was retrieve from the database. In your example the pattern to parse `01:00` will be `HH:mm` because it is hour and minutes.

```
String strFromDB = "01/29/02 01:00";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(strFromDB);
```

For reference
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html