# How can I convert milliseconds into the corresponding date right?

Tags: java, date, gmt

I have a problem with dates.

I'm sure these milliseconds 1317322560000, represent the date of Thu Sep 29 18:56:00 GMT+02:00 2011 in Italy.

But using the Calendar class the date is Thu Sep 29 20:56:00 GMT+02:00. I think this happens because, the summer schedule is in effect.

how can I convert milliseconds into the corresponding date right?

Comment: Where di you get Thu Sep 29 18:56:00 GMT+02:00 from?

Comment: From System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Please accept some answers. If the answer is correct, you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.currentTimeMillis()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)  returns "the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC." (i.e. GMT).

So the "Date" 1317322560000 you have, is 29/09/2011:18:56:00 GMT. In Italy, on 29th Sep the offset from GMT is +2 hours (because of "summer time" or technically speaking DST = [Daylight Saving Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time)). From 30/10/2011:03:00:00 (next sunday by the way), in Italy they will be in "winter time" (no DST), so the offset will be +1).

So you correctly get Thu Sep 29 20:56:00 CEST 2011 (18:56:00 + 2 hours offset in Italy's time zone). Please check this code that shows all this stuff (it is Groovy).

```
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.util.TimeZone

println Locale.getDefault()
Date d = new Date(1317322560000)
println d
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("it", "IT"))
println Locale.getDefault()

DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL);
println df.getTimeZone().getOffset(1317322560000) + " => +2h offset in 'summer time' (DST on)"

df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+00:00"))
println df.format(d)
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+01:00"))
println df.format(d)
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+02:00"))
println df.format(d)
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"))
println df.format(d)
println "---"

Date winterDate = new Date(1321382560000)
println winterDate
println df.getTimeZone().getOffset(1321382560000) + " => +1h offset in 'winter time' (DST off)"
```

The result of this:

```
es_ES
Thu Sep 29 20:56:00 CEST 2011
it_IT
7200000 => +2h offset in 'summer time' (DST on)
giovedì 29 settembre 2011 18.56.00 GMT+00:00
giovedì 29 settembre 2011 19.56.00 GMT+01:00
giovedì 29 settembre 2011 20.56.00 GMT+02:00
giovedì 29 settembre 2011 20.56.00 CEST
---
Tue Nov 15 19:42:40 CET 2011
3600000 => +1h offset in 'winter time' (DST off)
```

Comment: You can check also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java

Comment: It's ok, but if I want to create a calendar from this dataformat and when I request the date, the result is 20.56

Comment: It will display 18:56 if the timezone is GMT+00:00, 19:56 if TZ is GMT+01:00 and 20:56 if TZ is GMT+02:00, which is your case. There is no way you get a different result if your timezone is GMT+2. So I guess that when you got "18:56" you were running the code with the timezone set to GMT+0.

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(1317322560000l)`

outputs

`Thu Sep 29 20:56:00 CEST 2011`

same as your calendar. Why should it be `18:56`?

Comment: Yes, but the result will not change

Comment: Why those milliseconds were recorded at exactly 18:56 in Italy

Comment: I think with System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: This means if you did new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) at 18:56 it would have displayed 20:56.. Can you try it now to see if there is the same 2-hour gap ?

Comment: I try now System.currentTimeMillis() and the result is Fri Oct 28 11:32:24 GMT+02:00 2011, and it's ok date!!!

Comment: Can I convert a date in milliseconds GMT +0000, without summer time?

Comment: 1317322560000 milliseconds are GMT+0000.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed *Thu Sep 29 20:56:00 GMT+02:00*. i.e. the corresponding date-time in UTC is *Thu Sep 29 18:56:00Z* where `Z` stands for Zulu and is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset (`+00:00` hours offset or the `Etc/UTC` timezone).

### Solution using `java.time`, the modern API

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1317322560000L);

        // In Rome
        ZonedDateTime zdtRome = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));
        System.out.println(zdtRome);

        // In UTC
        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(zdtRome.format(dtf));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-09-29T20:56+02:00[Europe/Rome]
2011-09-29T18:56Z[Etc/UTC]
Thu Sep 29 2011 20:56:00+02:00
Thu Sep 29 2011 18:56:00Z
```

Learn more about the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>