# How to conert local time to UTC time in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

how to convert local time am/pm format in utc time.
`String localtime=12:00 AM;
 String UtcTime= ?;
//how to get UTC time.

`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java