# Getting date in GMT from unix timestamp

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, gmt

I have written the following code to get the date in GMT from a unix timestamp

```
private Date converToDate(String unixTimeStamp)
{
    //unix timestamps have GMT time zone.
    DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    //date obtained here is in IST on my system which needs to be converted into GMT.
    Date time = new Date(Long.valueOf(unixTimeStamp) * 1000);

    String result = gmtFormat.format(time);

    return lineToDate(result, true);
}
```

this code upon execution has

```
Mon May 27 02:57:32 IST 2013
```

value in the date variable and

```
Sun May 26 21:27:32 GMT 2013
```

in the result variable , How do I directly get the value in result variable into date variable ?

Comment: that gives the result in string , I m getting it in String but What I want is that result should be a Date not a String.

Comment: See the response http://stackoverflow.com/a/2453820/2235132 in the question above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem, conceptually:

```
//date obtained here is in IST on my system which needs to be converted into GMT.
Date time = new Date(Long.valueOf(unixTimeStamp) * 1000);
```

A `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone. This is the value you want. The fact that when you call `toString()` it converts it to your local time zone is irrelevant to the value that it's actually representing. A `Date` is *just* a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (1st January 1970, midnight UTC). So your whole method can be:

```
private static Date convertToDate(String unixTimeStamp)
{
    return new Date(Long.valueOf(unixTimeStamp) * 1000);
}
```

You don't need any kind of formatter, as you're not really trying to get a textual representation.

I would advise you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for date/time work if you can, by the way - it's a much cleaner API.

Answer (score 3):

A Date is just the wrapper for a long, which contains a number of milliseconds.

What you're seeing is the default `toString()` representation of the Date object, which uses your default timezone (IST) to transform the date into a readable string. If you want the date represented as a string using the GMT timezone, just do what you did: use a date format with the GMT time zone.

The Date object represents an instant on the universal timeline, and doesn't have any timezone.