# GMT in java, simple but not working

Tags: java, datetime, gmt, milliseconds

## This is both a duplicate and not a duplicate!

Just please help me and don't refer me to anywhere else, cause I'm really unable to get the GMT time.
The answer seems easy but it doesn't work for me.
I don't know are the answers all aver the web wrong, or am I making a mistake?

Please take a look at this snippet and the results:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
Date date = new Date(time);
System.out.println(date);

time = System.currentTimeMillis();
date = new Date(time);
System.out.println("--\n" + date);
```

result :

Fri Feb 28 16:07:12 GMT+03:30 2014
--
Fri Feb 28 16:07:12 GMT+03:30 2014

Both show my local time. I even printed directly the time, cause I thought maybe this is due to Date class but even those are the same (with just about 1 or 2 milliseconds difference).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeZone()` on a `SimpleDateFormat` to print the date in a specific timezone.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

Date d = format.parse("28-Feb-2014 13:00:00 PST");
System.out.println(format.format(d));

format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(format.format(d));
```

Prints:

```
28-Feb-2014 13:00:00 PST
28-Feb-2014 21:00:00 GMT
```

Comment: Thanks,so can I store the time in millisecond achieved via Calendar#getTimeInMillis and just use your instructions at the retrieval time?

Comment: Yes, store the millisecond value and when you format it for display, set the timezone you want to display it in.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and the [`setTimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) method():

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "..." );
sdf.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "GMT" ) );   // or UTC
System.out.println( sdf.format( date ) );
```

Cheers,

Comment: Would you please complete your answer so as to I can test it.

Comment: You should be able to read the Javadoc for SimpleDateFormat and work from there...

Comment: Oops.Thanks but seems aetheria did it without a bill!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(f.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

Comment: Good of you to add an identical answer to the two there are already :-)