# Convert DateTimeZone to UTC Offset

Tags: java, jodatime

Given a `DateTimeZone`, I can get the name and ID of the TimeZone like this:

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = new DateTimeZone("America/Chicago");

// Prints "America/Chicago"
System.out.println(timeZone.getID());

// Prints "CDT" (Since it is daylight savings time now)
System.out.println(timeZone.getNameKey(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()));

// Prints "Central Daylight Time"
System.out.println(timeZone.getName(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()));
```

All are great, but I really would like to get the timezone as a UTC offset.  In this case the UTC offset would look like `-05:00`

How do I do this with Joda-Time?

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19632076/2055998) answers your question.

Comment: [Time Zone != Offset](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info)

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#UTC

Comment: The offset depends of the date as it changes with the time (such as daylight savings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure Joda-solution looks like:

```
int offsetMillis =
    DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago").getOffset(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis());
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forOffsetMillis(offsetMillis);
String utcOffset = zone.toString();
System.out.println(utcOffset); // output: -05:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and `TimeZone` to achieve what you want.
Make a `SimpleDateFormat` by setting the `TimeZone` you want. And then use that to format a `new Date();`