# Generate Timestamp in IST Timezone java

Tags: java, timezone, timestamp, gmt

I am trying to generate current timestamp in GMT timezone but it is still getting generated in IST as my machine is set to IST. I am using this code.
Please help!!

```
{      String timeZone = "GMT";
   Calendar gmtCalendar =          Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone)); 
   Date date = gmtCalendar.getTime();
   endTime = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
   String eTime = NLSUtil.getFormattedDate(AdfUtil.getClientLocale(), new    java.sql.Date(endTime.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have no idea what NLSUtil is (can you elaborate?) but time formats have a timezone too (which defaults to the machine's timezone, IST in your case?)

```
Date toPrint = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(format.format(toPrint));
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
System.out.println(format.format(toPrint));
```

prints:

```
2015-01-16 10:18:34.604 GMT
2015-01-16 02:18:34.604 PST
```

Comment: Thanks radai, sorry for pasting local api.
SimpleDateFormat works, but I am trying to get either Timestamp or Date object out of it. Please let me know if it is feasible.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat has a parse() method which accepts a String as an argument and returns  Date object - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-

Answer (score 0):

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

//Local time zone   
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

//Time in GMT
System.out.println(dateFormatLocal.parse( dateFormatGmt.format(new Date()) ));
```

Please Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Add `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` before getting the instance