# Get UTC time for an android app

Tags: android, utc

Im currently working on the android application, in which i want to get UTC time from the internet and identify the current local time.

Im a newbie to android development, can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Comment: What do you mean by `get UTC time from the internet` ? from your server?

Comment: No not from my server,some common place/server which shows the exact  time(UTC), from which i can convert it to local timing based on the different locations

Comment: i am getting this error.      Unable to execute HTTP request: Write error: ssl=0xb79c18d8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

you using code in same java