# Get UTC equivalent Date for a particular timeZone (say US/Pacific) in Java

Tags: java

I would like to get the equivalent `UTC` time for a particular `timeZone` in Java as a `Date Object` (not as a string for displaying). Say I need to set the `Date` property as current `US/Pacific` time plus 1 hour. Currently if the `US/Pacific` time is 08.30am then I need the `UTC` equivalent of 09.30am `US/Pacific`. How can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code. You may create a method to return Date instance. Hope it helps. 
Thanks.

```
DateFormat utcDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    utcDateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    DateFormat pacificFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    pacificFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Pacific"));
    //add 1 hour to Date
    Calendar pacificCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    pacificCal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    System.out.println("PACIFIC TIME WITH ADDED HOUR : " +pacificFormatter.format(pacificCal.getTime()));

    String temp = utcDateFormatter.format(pacificCal.getTime());
    System.out.println("GMT DATE TIME: " +temp);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date gmtDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(temp);
    //return gmtDate
    System.out.println("GMT DATE: " + gmtDate);
```