# How to get the real UTC Timestamp regardless the device Time (not Timezone)

Tags: android, datetime, timestamp, device

Is there a way in Android to get the current timestamp regardless the Time setted in Device Settings?

I dont have a problem with timeoffset which is out of the timezones. My problem is, that if i set a wrong Time in my Device-Settings the Timestamp i get from the System is based on this wrong Time.

Current UTC Timestamp is `1447164873` it is `10.11.2015 14:14:33` and `15:14:33` Local (my Timezone is +1:00)

if i call `System.currentTimeMillis() /1000` i get the right `Timestamp = 1447164873;`

if i go to the Device Settings and set the Time of my Device one Hour to the Future (16:14:33), `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000` returns the wrong `Timestamp = 1447168473` which is `15:14:33` and `16:14:33` local.

Is there a possibility to get the real UTC Timestamp regardless the Time set on my Device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Comment: I see... You can't get the real UTC timestamp if your the Time set in the device is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the correct timestamp if the device time is set wrong.

but the way to solve this problem is to create an API that gives the current timestamp in the backend or a simple lambda function.
And use it whenever you need, here API round trip time should be considered to get the accurate timestamp 
Or
Just hit the API once on the app open and start a counter of your own to calculate the timestamp.

I have used this method in one of my IoT projects to get timestamps in the microcontroller.