# How to get time with GMT like 2016-02-28/20:31 GMT

Tags: java

I want time with GMT string too.

But Im not able to get it.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd/hh-mm");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println("date "+dateFormat.format(date));
```

But Im getting like this 2015-12-28/11-53
without GMT at the end

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java

Comment: this has been asked and answered before in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd/hh-mm z");
 dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

instead of

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd/hh-mm");
```

where `'z'` means timezone

Comment: Im getting IST but i need GMT

Comment: @Azat Nugusbayev u rocks