# SimpleDateFormat.parse("MM/yyyy")

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I am trying to implement a method which parses `String` to `Date`, and I would like to use `SimpleDateFormat` because that seems to do the work:

```
java.util.Date parseMonth(String str) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
    return format.parse(str);
}
```

But for some reasons, I get no `ParseException` on inputs where I expect to get one.

- "00/2000" -> 1999-12-01, no Exception
- "13/2000" -> 2001-01-01, no Exception

What is the preferred way to check if a `String` is a correct date (in respect to some implementation depended format)?

Comment: This question has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or

Comment: Everybody has their own way I prefer regex validator.

Comment: I recommend you avoid `SimpleDateFormat`. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with. Look into its `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter` classes.

Comment: Duplicate of: [*How to parse date with only month and year*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46780340/642706). See [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780431/642706) by Andreas using the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is lenient by default, so it tries to be smart (usually failing) and doing things like *"month zero becomes December of previous year"*.

To make invalid inputs throw an exception, just disable the lenient behaviour:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
format.setLenient(false); // not lenient
```

This will throw a `ParseException` for invalid inputs, such as `00/2000` and `13/2000`.

---

But now we have better API's for that. Since Java 8, there's a [new date/time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), and for versions <= 7 there's a [nice backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp). In this API, the formatters are not lenient by default:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yyyy");
YearMonth.parse("00/2000", fmt); // exception
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Doesn't `setLenient` solve the problem?

Comment: I don’t know if that’s the case here. but some users like to downvote answers to downvoted and/or duplicate questions in order to avoid too many such questions. This is a good answer. One might still argue that it’s better to keep the answers where the original question is.