# Getting date/time in server side code for specific Timezone

Tags: java

On the server code I would like to get the "Day" but not of server date/time but of a specific timezone, GMT+8 specifically.

I have this code:

```java
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH);
String day = formatter.format(new Date()).toUpperCase();
availabilities.add(Availability.builder()
   .day(day)
   .from(LocalTime.now())
   .to(LocalTime.now())
   .build());
```

How do I get the "day" for the specific timezone and also have to build a `LocalTime.now()` which will return a `LocalTime` object but not the current time of the said timezone.

For instance as of this writing GMT+8 now is ~6:25 am so that would be the one that `LocalTime.now()` returns instead of the cloud server which is in the different timezone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the current date and time in UTC or GMT in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308683/how-can-i-get-the-current-date-and-time-in-utc-or-gmt-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

SDF and `new Date()` are old API and you don't want these. For example, `Date` is a lie; it does **not** represent a date whatsoever, it actually represents an instant in time. This is dumb - that's why there is a new API.

EDIT: Made it simpler by invoking the `now` method of `ZonedDateTime`.

```
private static final ZoneId TARGET_ZONE = ZoneId.of("Singapore");


ZonedDateTime atTarget = ZonedDateTime.now(TARGET_ZONE);
DayOfWeek whatYouWant = atTarget.getDayOfWeek();
```

NB: You can go with +8 explicitly, then you're looking for an `OffsetDateTime`, and `atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8))`, but that's... weird. Who could possibly want 'UTC+8'? Nobody, except airplanes and military operations in a certain zone, and surely that's not your target audience.

Comment: Why not call [`ZonedDateTime now(TARGET_ZONE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-)?